# Find the upper and the lower bounds for a definite integral

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals, maxima-minima

I have a question like

> Find a lower bound and an upper bound for the area under the curve by
>   finding the minimum and maximum values of the integrand on the given
>   integral:

$$
\int_1^6t^2-6t+11 \ dt
$$

> It asks for two answers; a minimum area and a maximum
>   area.

So, I integrate this;

$$
\left(\frac{t^3}{3}-3t^2+11t\right)\Bigg|_1^6
$$

I know I have a minimum at $x = 3$ because;

$$
f(t) = t^2-6t+11 \\
f'(t) = 2t-6 = 0 \\
2(t-3) = 0 \\
t = 3 \\
f(5) = 4 \\
f(1) = -4 \\
$$

Very confused by what is going on when it asks for a maximum area and a minimum area.

Comment: A function can have a minimum and maximum value where the derivative isn't $0$. Specifically, where its derivative isn't defined and, perhaps more relevant to this problem, at the end points of where the function is defined. Of course, just as for when the derivative is $0$, you have to actually _check_ whether these are max / min values.

Comment: Are you sure you have reproduced the question correctly or is something lost in paraphrasing?  As stated, the question seems a bit absurd - the definite integral is a rational number, so speaking of its maximum and minimum doesn't make much sense.

Comment: This is exactly how it is phrased in the book

Comment: @Macavity, it says 'upper bound' and 'lower bound' which makes sense. I will edit the title accordingly

Comment: But the bounds are already included $[1,6]$

Answer (score 3):

$$f(t)=t^2-6t+11=(t-3)^2+2$$

which is a convex quadratic function. It has a unique minimum.

The boundary points are $1$ and $6$, we can evaluate these points and conclude that $f(6)$ is bigger. $f(6)$ is the global maximum. (or just observe that the quadratic curve is symmetrical about $t=3$ and the value increases the further away we are from $3$).

Hence,  $$\forall t \in [1,6], f(3) \leq f(t) \leq f(6)$$

$$\int_1^6 f(3) dt \leq \int_1^6 f(t) dt \leq \int_1^6 f(6) dt$$

$$5 f(3) \leq \int_1^6f(t)dt \leq 5f(6)$$

Of course, $f(3)$ and $f(6)$ can be evaluated easily.

Comment: I do not understand this.

Comment: which part? do you understand why $f(3) \leq f(t) \leq f(6)$? or is it other part that you are confused about?

Comment: Is $f(3)$ chosen because the zero of $(t-3)^2+2 = 3$? And if so, why choose to include $f(6)$ and not $f(1)$?

Comment: Also where does 5 come from?

Comment: $f(3)$ is chosen because $(t-3)^2+2 \geq 2$ and this minimal is attaiend when $t=3$, that is when we zero out the first term.   We can evaluate $f(6)$ and $f(1)$ and see which number is bigger.

Comment: $\int_1^6 f(6) dt = f(6) \int_1^6 1 dt$ Do you see where does the $5$ comes from?

Comment: No. I don't see where it comes from since $\int_1^6f(x)=\frac{65}{3}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60865/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-computer).